# TtileProvider blank page - Google Maps API, own tile provider

Tags: google-maps, tiles, android, mbtiles

I'm using Google Maps API to display mbtiles map hosted locally on my server. Tile service works fine (checked via requsts). But when I apply it to my Kotlin app nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

    googleMap.mapType=GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE
    mMap = googleMap

        mMap.addTileOverlay(TileOverlayOptions()
                .tileProvider(MyTileProvider())
                .transparency(0.5f)
                .zIndex(3000f)
        )
    }
```

And MyTileProvider class

```
class MyTileProvider : UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {

    override fun getTileUrl(x: Int, y: Int, zoom: Int): URL {
       
       
        val s = "http://my_tile_server/$zoom/$x/$y.png"

        try {
            return URL(s)

        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            throw AssertionError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

OSM tile provider also does not display tiles.. (https://tile.openstreetmap.org/$zoom/$x/$y.png)

When I check the URL from logs and paste it to web browser tiles works perfectly ( e.g. http://my_tile_provider/5/17/10.png )

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried "https" in the string in your app (for `val s`) instead of "http"?

Comment: No, in my own tile server not - I am hosting it on rasbperry, but I've tried with OSM (https) tile service - the result is the same - no tiles. Here's logs and value of string "s" (val s) "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/9/286/169.png"

Comment: To perform another test I've added my own tile service to third party app found on Play Store to test wheter my service is working or not. To my surprise my tiles are loading and displaying correctly!